# How to wait for a HTMX request to finish, and then trigger a new HTMX request?

Tags: htmx

How to fix this? I tried also `htmx:xhr:loadend` and `htmx:afterrequest` , in both it was the same problem, only with timeout was working

```js
document.addEventListener('htmx:afterSwap', function(evt) {

    //.... wait for a POST with path /add-song ....
    
    //DOESNT WORK, i cant trigger new HTMX event, immediatly, its ignored
    lastSong.dispatchEvent(new Event("play-song-event"));

    //WORKS AFTER 1sec
    setTimeout(function ()
    {
      lastSong.dispatchEvent(new Event("play-song-event"));
    },1000);
    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it, i needed `'htmx:afterSettle'` instead of `'htmx:afterSwap'`